Connected to wifi but no internet connection
I just installed endeavouros on my laptop and at first I thought everything was ok because i used a wired connection and i had access to the internet, but when i later tried wifi i couldn't connect to or ping to any website. I connected to wifi with iwctl and it shows that i am conected but nmcli shows that i am not connected. I think the problem is that I don't have a gateway ip adress or a default route because when i use the route command it only returns this:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination   Gateway   Genmask Flags Metric Ref   Use Iface

When i tried to add a route with sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 (i got this address from another forum post but i have seen a lot of other adresses on different forums, but i don't know what i should use because everyon exept me seems to have one) i only got this error:
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway. 

I don't know what i should do because I haven't been able to find anyone with this problem yet.
Sorry if i misunderstood something or if used the wrong terms but I don't have a lot of experience with internet problems.
Edit: I just found out that the internet works perfectly fine when i use KDE Plasma instead of Hyprland, which i used before. On Plasma i connected to wifi using the GUI and it worked and i had internet access and the route command also had a normal output. When I tried using the GUI on Hyprland it did not work. Is this a Hyprland specific bug or did I mess something up when i installed it?
Edit 2:
Reopening this question because it turns out the Problem isn't completely gone. After I followed the steps by metablaster it worked, but when I restart or close and reopen (suspend) the laptop the route just disappears and I can't use the internet anymore. When testing if it worked on KDE Plasma, i logged out, switched from hyprland to Plasma and tried it there and there it worked. When I then log out again and back into hyprland i have the internet access and the route command also has a normal output again. This only works if I log in to hyprland first, but not if I log into Plasma first and then hyprland. If I interpret this correctly, Plasma somehow creates the route and hyprland keeps it, but only if hyprland has been running before. Can I write something like a startupscript that does, whatever Plasma does to make the internet work because it's kinda annoying to always log into hyprland, then Plasma and back into hyprland just to be able to have internet access.

Could you give more details on how do you connect? The full command line, and also the configuration (just replace SSID and passwords with ***)

I use iwctl and i connect with wps because for me that's the simplest option.
1: wsc list
2: wsc device push-button
and than i press the wps button on the router

Your edit is unrelated to original problem, instead of marking my answer as no longer accepted which btw you said it worked and solved it, you should have created a new question titled Adding permanent static routes and then reference this question to provide more details.

I said it worked, because i thought it worked, but as it turned out it did not anymore after rebooting. I found this out just recently because I didn't use the laptop in the meantime. As for editing the original question instead of making a new one: In my opinion your solution didn't completely fix the original problem because it only worked temporarily

Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway. 

To get around this error message you need to specify onlink while adding default gateway as follows:
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 src 10.10.10.10 onlink

In the above command replace wlan0 with your WI-FI NIC name and replace src address with IP address configured on that NIC.
To learn NIC name and IP address run ip a command which will list NIC name and configured address for that WI-FI NIC.
You can also try shorter way with just:
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 onlink

If the default gateway provides DHCP function then you can also add proto dhcp to the line, for instance:
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp onlink

If you'll be using static IP then use proto static instead and do not omit src <ip address> portion which must be configured on NIC prior to adding route.
